# How can I rander array withen array in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contactId] => 5
            [companyId] => 54
            [personName] => Awais
            [contactNo] => 0321-1111111
            [contactType] => Partner
        )
)
data[0].personName
```

I have read so many questions but it is still shows nothing and saying undefiend. 
can any one tell me how can I show this array in html..
this is actually AJAX response.

Comment: The code you posted looks like the output of PHP's print_r... Can you post your code that attempts to handle the array and render contents?

Comment: yes it is output off print_r.
this is return from ajax call to my desire page and i want it to parse in simple array and show it i html

Comment: Yes OK. So, here at SO, it's not about what you want but how to make something work better that you've already done. That's why we'd like to see how your code fails so we can give hints how to fix it.

Comment: instead print_r return json data using echo json_encode($yourArray); and in js you can parse json using parseJSON()

Comment: parseJson() not working after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

*Seems* like your ajax respone is from this php:

```
print_r($array);
```

What you need is:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: then how can i access this?

Comment: Depends on how you fetch the data. getJSON() is an excellent start http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/